# Desempaquetar en python

Tags: python

me gustaría saber si me podeís decir alguna manera de saber como desempaquetar #octets. Esto es una implementación de TFTP con extensión de la opcion del tamaño del bloque. (SERVIDOR)

> |  opc | nombre de archivo |  0 |  modo |  0 |  blksize |  0 |  #octets |  0 |
>
> |  1 |  foobar |  0 |  octeto  0 |  blksize |  0 |  1428 |  0 |

Sé que debo usar struct.unpack(), pero nó se como acceder por ejemplo a 1428.
por ejemplo:

```
msg = sock.recvfrom(512)
opcode = struct.unpack('!HH'. msg[:2])
```

Gracias. [RFC 1350](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350) , [RFC 2348](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2348)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desempaquetar la petición no es tan simple como empaquetarla por la sencilla razón de que a priori solo conocemos que los dos primeros bytes pertenecen al `opc`. El resto pueden tener un número variable de bytes, limitados por un byte nulo siempre.

Por lo tanto, debemos iterar sobre cada uno de los bytes e ir identificando los bytes nulos, generando de forma adecuada el formato para `struct.unpack`.

Otro tema a tener en cuenta, es que hay argumentos opcionales como son `Windowsize` (RFC 7440), `Blocksize`, `Timeout`, etc que pueden o no estar presentes.

En principio, puedes hacer algo así:

```
def decode(buffer):
    if not buffer:
        raise ValueError("No se pudo decodificar, buffer vacío")

    fmts = [b"!H"]
    nulls = 0
    last = 0

    for pos, byte in enumerate(buffer[2:]):
        if not byte:
            num_bytes = pos - last
            if not num_bytes:
                raise ValueError("Buffer con estructura malformada")
            fmts.append(b"%dsx" % num_bytes)
            nulls += 1
            last = pos + 1

    if nulls % 2:
        raise ValueError("Buffer con estructura malformada")

    fmt = b"".join(fmts)
    args_struct = struct.unpack(fmt, buffer)
    opc = args_struct[0]
    filename = args_struct[1].decode("utf-8")
    mode = args_struct[2].decode("utf-8")
    opt_struct = iter(args_struct[3:])
    options = {opt.decode("utf-8"): value.decode("utf-8") for opt, value in zip(opt_struct, opt_struct)}
    return opc, filename, mode, options
```

> ```
> >>> buffer = b'\x00\x02foobar.txt\x00octect\x00'
> >>> opc, filename, mode, options = decode(buffer)
> >>> print(opc, filename, mode, options)
> 2 foobar.txt octect {}
>
> >>> buffer = b'\x00\x02foobar.txt\x00octect\x00blksize\x001428\x00'
> >>> opc, filename, mode, options = decode(buffer)
> >>> print(opc, filename, mode, options)
> 2 foobar.txt octect {'blksize': '1428'}
>
> >>> buffer = b'\x00\x02foobar.txt\x00octect\x00blksize\x001428\x00windowsize\x0016\x00'
> >>> opc, filename, mode, options = decode(buffer)
> >>> print(opc, filename, mode, options)
> 2 foobar.txt octect {'blksize': '1428', 'windowsize': '16'}
>
> >>> buffer = b'\x00\x02foobar.txt\x00'
> >>> opc, filename, mode, options = decode(buffer)
>
> Exception has occurred: ValueError
>     Buffer con estructura malformada
> ```